# Can anyone explain the output of mixedmirt function in mirt package?

Tags: r

[image: the output]

I would like to include person-item covariates in the item response model(eg:2PL model), but I am confused with how to interpret the output
(shown in the picture). Like how to understand the relationship between the coefficients of groupG1 and a1(or d)? 
Below is my code:

```r
#make some data
set.seed(1234)
N <- 750
a <- matrix(rlnorm(10,.3,1),10,1)
d <- matrix(rnorm(10), 10)
Theta <- matrix(sort(rnorm(N)))
pseudoIQ <- Theta * 5 + 100  + rnorm(N, 0 , 5)
pseudoIQ <- (pseudoIQ - mean(pseudoIQ))/10  #rescale variable for numerical stability
group <- factor(rep(c('G1','G2','G3'), each = N/3))
data <- simdata(a,d,N, itemtype = rep('2PL',10), Theta=Theta)
covdata <- data.frame(group, pseudoIQ)
#specify IRT model
model <- 'Theta = 1-10'
# 2PL model
mod2 <- mixedmirt(data, covdata, model, fixed = ~ 0 + group + items + pseudoIQ,itemtype = '2PL')

coef(mod2)
```

Comment: what is `model`?

Comment: @JonnyPhelps  Sorry, I added the code.